# Samsung Galaxy Note 4 restarting continuously

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, system-error, samsung-galaxy-note-4

My Samsung Galaxy Note 4 has been continuously restarting during or at times right after the welcome screen. I have tried the following steps to sort out this issue:

1. Downloaded Samsung USB driver and installed it.
2. Downloaded Odin version 3.12.3.
3. Downloaded firmware for my Note 4 SM-910F from SamMobile.com .
4. Delete the cache.img.ext4 from the firmware .md5 file before flashing it with Odin. (Is this a good practice?)
5. Once the firmware is loaded in Odin I turn on my mobile phone and set it to download mode by pressing Home+Power+Volume Down button.
6. Once Flash is completed I restart my mobile by taking out the battery and then press the Power+Home+Volume Up button together to get to the recovery screen.
7. Once in the recovery screen I wipe the cache partition and data/factory reset as well. During the data/factory reset process a verify dmverity hash tree... comes up and then my mobile goes back into the endless restart cycle.

While in the Android recovery menu I have noticed that right at the end it's written: `dm-verity verification failed`.

From this point onward though I feel I have done everything by the book and my mobile is still restarting continuously. This is the first time I have dealt with such a problem and I am new to the whole process of flashing the firmware itself.

Comment: What changes occurred before this issue started happening? Is the device rooted? I might be wrong, but dm-verity verification failure could part of the problem.

Comment: If I remember correctly no new app had been download and installed for nearly 3 months. The device is not rooted.